# MySQL determine human years from horse (Times 3)

Tags: mysql, date

I'm sorry, i have searched the threads and tried till my brain hurts but i have to ask for help.

I have a table called "Horse" with Id, Name, Born (Year only), Colour, Died.

I need to return the age of the horses that have died, and multiply by 3 to get the human years and display the horses ID, Name, and Human Years.

I am stuck at the very first hurdle. I cant get the table to return the Horses age.

I am using the suggestions of another SO user;

select DATEDIFF(horse.born, '2012') / 365.25 as Human Years

However this returns Null.

Also tried a CURDATE:

CURDATE('%Y%')-Born as Human Years
FROM horse;

No good. Any tips?

Comment: is `Died` a boolean? or a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column `Born` contains only a year (as an integer, presumably?) you won't be able to perform date-math on it. And you're likely to run into trouble with a column name like `Human Years` with a space in it. Or is that a typo?

Anyway, try something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (YEAR(CURDATE()) - Born) * 3 AS Human_Years
  FROM horse
  WHERE Died IS NOT NULL
```

Or is `Died` a Date-field? In which case you probably want something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name,
  (DATEDIFF(Died, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Born, "-08-01"),"%Y-%m-%d")/365.25 * 3 AS Human_Years
  FROM horse
  WHERE Died IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks RET, looks like that was the problem. I have Died as an integer. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes born is an 'int' and died is 'date':

```
select (Year(died)-born) * 3 from horse where died is not null
```

(Also, since all race horses are considered to be born on the 1st of January, fractional years can be ignored).